# how to update/ append values to a knockout list

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm failing to add an additem method to append items to my list using javascript together with knockout.  Any advice appreciated, many thanks, James

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rxkU3/2/

**Code snippet**

```
window.Helper= {
    Start: function (tagging) {
        var viewModel = ...
        window.Helper.ViewModel = viewModel;
        viewModel.Keywords = ko.observable();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);        
    },

    MyMethod: function() {
      // Not sure how to get this working??
    },
    AMethod: function () {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: The method should be on the ViewModel not the closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a 'add' function:

```
viewModel.toAdd = ko.observable();
viewModel.add = function () {
    viewModel.Article.Keywords( viewModel.Article.Keywords() + "|" + viewModel.toAdd()  );

};
```

And the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxkU3/3/

Comment: I'm guessing the toAdd holds the value to add and the Keywords() is the current array.  Is that correct?  Just want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: in the jsfiddle, why is the button using weird markup?  i.e. an input with a button inside it?  Unfortunately this causes a runtime parser error when adding it into the working file.

Comment: what do you mean by "weird markup" ? 'button' is a html5 markup. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/button.html

Comment: thanks, is it possible to write it differently?  thanks